Installed font does not appear in xfontsel on a Guix System
After installing font-terminus on my Guix System the font appears in the output of fc-list
...
/home/rovanion/.guix-profile/share/fonts/terminus/ter-x12n.pcf.gz: Terminus:style=Regular
...
/run/current-system/profile/share/fonts/terminus/ter-x14n.pcf.gz: Terminus:style=Regular
...

but is not selectable in xfontsel nor can urxvt find it when specified as
URxvt*font:                           -*-terminus-medium-r-*-*-13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

I have tried installing all three outputs, font-terminus, font-terminus:pcf-8bit and font-terminus:otb but to no avail.
Using xset q I can see that the Font Path does not seem to include anything about terminus. Is there some magic that's missing from Guix or some understanding that's missing from my side?

As stated on its homepage, Fontconfig is a library for configuring and customizing font access, which is independent of X. The command fc-list(1) is a part of Fontconfig.
xfontsel uses the X Athena Widget Set (Xaw), which depends on the built-in font handling in X, which predates Fontconfig and FreeType.
Assuming that the directory /run/current-system/profile/share/fonts/terminus has the fonts.dir file (for scalable fonts, also fonts.scale) - if not, commands mkfontdir(1) and mkfontscale(1) can be used to generate them - using xset(1)'s +fp option, a directory can be added to a font path, for example:
xset +fp /run/current-system/profile/share/fonts/terminus

after which the X server should be instructed to reread the font databases in the font path:
xset fp rehash

After that, you should be able to use the fonts in that directory, for example:
urxvt -fn '*-terminus-*-18-*'

The above invocations of xset(1) can be added to a user initialization file (for example, $HOME/.xsession or $HOME/.xinitrc).
Note: From @Rovanion's comment, it seems that Guix uses symlinks, which are not read properly by X. There are two solutions in that case: either add the directory holding actual files (plus the files fonts.dir and fonts.scale) to the font path, or copy the font files to a location in the font path, regenerating fonts.dir and fonts.scale.

xset +fp /run/current-system/profile/share/fonts/terminus/ sadly didn't work, probably because it contains symlinks. But following that symlink and running /gnu/store/<hash>-fonts-dir/share/fonts/terminus/ works, as well as xset fp rehash. Sadly urxvt -fn '*-terminus-*-18-*' still failed to load the font.
Thinking the issue might be symlinks again i ran cp -rL /gnu/store/<hash>-fonts-dir/share/fonts/terminus /tmp/ft and xset +fp /tmp/ft and after xset fp rehash urxvt successfully started.
I conclude that Guix needs some hacking.

I never used Guix, but on all the Unix-like systems I used so far, which use regular files instead of symlinks, the above method works. From your comment, it seems that on Guix you need to copy the files, or you can just add the location of actual files to font path.
